# Grayscale image not a jpeg

Tags: python, image, format, jpeg, python-imageio

I created a greyscale image like this

```
def create_new_image(size, luminance):
    width, height = size
    black_frame = int(luminance) * np.ones((width, height, 1), dtype=np.uint8)
    return black_frame
```

Where luminance is element of [0, 255]

I have saved the image using imageio

```
def save_image(image, output_path):
    imageio.imwrite(output_path, image)
```

Where the `output_path` is something like /valid_path/img.jpg

Now I want to load my grayscale image back:

```
img = imageio.imread(file, format ='jpg')
```

But what I get is a syntax error.

```
raise SyntaxError("not a JPEG file")
  File "<string>", line None
SyntaxError: not a JPEG file
```

If I don't specify the format, I get another error.

```
    "Could not find a format to read the specified file in %s mode" % modename
ValueError: Could not find a format to read the specified file in single-image mode
```

Why?
Thanks

Comment: please provide the **full script** to re-create the problem (including the python version and the library version used).

Comment: @Jürgen K. Can you show the exact value of `output_path`?

Comment: @DarK_FirefoX, `output_path` is simply a path somewhere in your machine. Example: `output_path = '/home/DarKFirefox/Document/your/path/'`. It is just a string.

Comment: @Leos313, I know it is supposed to be. I am just asking to check, because the problem he is having may as well be due to a wrong path to the image file. Because, as stated on the answers below: it worked for me just fine, even without specifying de `format=jpg`. `imageio` documentation states that it will choose the correct decoder/encoder according to the file (maybe the file extension). So @Jürgen K, I encourage you to `print(output_path)` and check if it is the correct path to the file.

Comment: @DarK_FirefoX, good point! right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try :

```
def save_image(image, output_path):
    imageio.imwrite(output_path, format= "jpg", image)
```

to explicitly state that it is a jpg file.

Answer (score 1):

JPEG files (compressed images) start with an image marker that always contains the marker code hex values FF D8 FF. It does not have a length of the file embedded, thus we need to find JPEG trailer, which is FF D9.

See the documentation using the link at [this page](https://www.file-recovery.com/jpg-signature-format.htm).

As en example, opening a jpeg image with a hexadecimal viewer (for example [Hex Viewer](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/)), you should see something like this:

[image]

**Solution**: In other words, try to add the header to the file before saving it as JPEG, you should solve your problem.

The page with the API's documentation can be found [here](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userapi.html). Following the doc, you should locate the right instruction that makes you specify the format for saving (as point out by @Meto in the answer).

Concluding: the solution is just specifying the format when you physically write the image in the hard disk:

```
imageio.imwrite(uri, im, format=None, **kwargs)
```

in your case `format=jpg`.

Moreover,

```
 imageio.show_formats()
```

Show a nicely formatted list of available formats.

Concluding, just try to replace

```
imageio.imwrite(output_path, image)
```

with

```
imageio.imwrite(output_path, image, format ='jpg' )
```

**Please note** that the solution is always the same in every answer. I have just added what happens specifying a format (i.e., just writes the right header).

Comment: ok, can you provide the code that you used to create the image? insert the whole script so I can try to have a look at the entire program.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure if your file is really saved as a JPG file.
On Linux/Mac you can use `file` command to verify that.

For example, below command confirms `fireside.jpg` is a JPEG file:

```
# file fireside.jpg
fireside.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, aspect ratio, density 1x1, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 2048x1365, components 3
```

If the file is not saved as JPG, try specifying file format="jpg" as

```
imageio.imwrite(output_path, image, format ='jpg')
```

Answer (score -1):

This works (Verified in jupyter notebook)

```
import numpy as np
import imageio

def create_new_image(size, luminance):
    width, height = size
    black_frame = int(luminance) * np.ones((width, height, 1), dtype=np.uint8)
    return black_frame

def save_image(image, output_path):
    imageio.imwrite(output_path, image)

img = create_new_image((256, 256), 125)
save_image(img, "test.jpg")
img1 = imageio.imread("test.jpg", format ='jpg')
```